# What is the meaning of the present tense used in the beginning of Kafka .. by Murakami?

Tags: tense

I'm confused about the present tense used in the beginning of Kafka on the Shore by Haruki Murakami. From what I understand the simple present in English can be used for things like "the sun rises everyday" but in the novel I couldn't figure out how to interpret it. I went to the french translation (I understand french better than English) it was written in a kind of past tense called in french "le passé composé" but not in the present.

The following is how the novel starts:

> Cash isn't the only thing I take from my father's study when I leave home. I take a small, old gold lighter—I like the design and feel of it—and a folding knife with a really sharp blade. Made to skin deer, it has a five-inch blade and a nice heft.

It would made sense if the narrator is leaving home everyday like the sun rises, but I suspect it isn't the case.

Comment: Please quote the text you are talking about. I haven't got a copy, and I suspect many other people here won't have either. But as a possible suggestion, see [historic present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present)

Comment: Japanese has 4 verb tenses while English has ~12. So, jp/eng translators often need freedom to translate verb tenses. Japanese has no future or perfect tenses.

Answer (score 3):

This is a technique called "[present tense narrative](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/how-to-write-a-novel-in-the-present-tense#how-to-write-in-present-tense-understanding-the-4-present-tenses)". One use of the present tense is "commentary"  For example a football commentator might say:

> Fenton passes the ball to Davis, who dribbles forward, dummies left then goes right. He shoots and scores! It's a goal!

The commentator is using the present tense to describe events at the moment that they happen.

A writer can use the present tense to give the impression that the events are happening right now. It creates "immediacy", as if the events of the novel are happening in real time.